# Can't access an exported shell variable from within a script?

Tags: bash, scripts, environment-variables

This is all while ssh'd into an AWS EC2 Ubuntu 18 instance.

In my ~/.bashrc:

```
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-west-2"
```

In the shell:

```
$ echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
us-west-2
```

But when I run this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "starting"

echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

I get this output:

```
starting
```

with an empty line below "starting".

Everything I've found on google is people who failed to export their vars, but mine is exported so I'm at a loss for what could be going wrong.

I've even tried to explicitly export the var from within the shell.

Comment: are you confident with the first line `#!/usr/bin/env bash
`?

Comment: How did you run the script?

Comment: Hello. According to @cmak.fr's comment, here is little [more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16365367/6543935). It is important, at which point you are executing the script - within CLI login-shell or some other environment as crontab? However in the certain case I thin you need to do log-out and log-in in order to source the `.bashrc` file, or you can explicitly source it instead by the command `. ~/.bashrc` then run your script again.

Comment: @pa4080 I am running the script after ssh'ing into the terminal. The .bashrc file was setup last night and the AWS instance has been stopped and started since then so it's not like I just added the "export" lines immediately before trying to run the script.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I ran the script with "sudo ./test.sh" and also "sudo bash ./test.sh". Both of which had identical behaviour.

Comment: @cmak.fr i tried no bang line, #!/bin/bash, and also #!/usr/bin/env bash. all 3 had identical behaviour.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson The issue was that when running with 'sudo', it doesn't have access to the environment vars. Not really sure why this is, but if i run it with 'sudo -E ./test.sh' it works as intended. Thanks for your simple question which led me down the right path :).

Comment: The variable doesn't belong to the root's environment (it is placed in your user's .bashrc as I understand correctly), this is the reason why `sudo ./test.sh` doesn't work as you are expecting.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "unclear" since the question omits essential information (i.e. that the script was being run using `sudo`)

Comment: @Patrick : please edit your question and add the essential information @steeldriver pointed ie the `sudo` non-detail. Solution : export your var from `/root/.bashrc`